# Magento Upsell Products not visible if it's category and products category are different

Tags: magento, collections, product

Hi i'm having below categories

```
Camera
  - DSLR
  - Digital Camers

Accessories
 - Lenses
 - Memory cards
```

I've added a `product from lenses category` as a upsell to a `product from Digital cameras`. but it's not displaying in frontend.

It can be viewable only if i add dslr as one more category for lens product `(Added as upsell to dslr product)`.

Is there any way to show upsell products from entirely different category?

Answer (score 1):

Cross check below things:

The products you want to show are:
 1. enabled
 2. visible on frontend
 3. in stock
 4. should have been assigned in atleast 1 category.
 5. must be visible in same website (in case of multi-websites).

then flush Magento cache and recheck frontend.

Comment: I have same situation. One of my upsell's product is set as "Not Visible Indivudially". So i set it visible in catalog,search and its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the product you want to display in upsell to the Default Category. This has been driving me crazy for the last hour - trial and error, worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and as workaround, I have added my product into the same category than my upsell products. In my case, my product is not visible (It is the target of google search) and I just change the visibility to search.

Magento executes the following query:

```
SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `links`.`link_id`, `link_attribute_position_int`.`value` AS `position` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = '1'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_link` AS `links` ON links.linked_product_id = e.entity_id AND links.link_type_id = 4
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_link_attribute_int` AS `link_attribute_position_int` ON link_attribute_position_int.link_id = links.link_id AND link_attribute_position_int.product_link_attribute_id = '4' 
WHERE (e.entity_id NOT IN((SELECT `sales_flat_quote_item`.`product_id` FROM `sales_flat_quote_item` WHERE (quote_id = '')))) AND (links.product_id = 678) AND (e.entity_id != '678') 
ORDER BY `position` ASC LIMIT 4
```

Here the category is '2' (cat_index.category_id = '2').

Otherwise you must modify the Magento code.